# Cannot open android emulator in eclipse

Tags: windows-7

When I try to run my application in eclipse as a android application, it shows the error," No space on the device". What am I supposed to do?

Comment: How much space does it have?

Answer (score 1):

[Answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604951/no-space-left-on-device-android)

If your drive has enough free space, then:

The system NAND flash for the emulator has run out of space. Your host system is not the issue, but for some reason the system.img file that represents a NAND flash for the emulator is full.

**Method 1 (easiest way)**

Create a new emulator.

**Method 2**

Do a factory default reset in the emulator to clean it up.

To do this, either issue a **Factory Data Reset** inside Android under `Settings -> Privacy`, or start the emulator from the command-line:

```
android list avd
emulator -avd My_Avd_Name -wipe-data
```

The first command list all Android Virtual Devices. You **need the name** for the second command. The emulator should not already be running.

**Method 3**

Delete the disk images located under your Windows profile. Under your profiles, it's `.android/avd/My_Avd_Name.avd` You should only need to delete `userdata-qemu.img` and maybe `cache.img`. You can try deleting other image files if necessarily, but note, `sdcard.img` won't be re-created automatically. You need to run `mksdcard` from the command-line.

**Method 4** [(From here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332797/no-space-left-on-android-emulator)

Apps are installed in `/data/apps`. Make sure that your data partition size is big enough to support your app.

If you are having trouble with 'No space Left' and you are sure that you aren't using all of the space on the device, then run

```
emulator.exe -avd <AvdName> -partition-size 512 -no-snapshot-load
```

Partition size will set size of system and data images in MB. You can change 512 to a greater value depending on your needs. `-no-snapshot-load` ensures that you are not booting from a snapshot and thus you see the new partition size.